# Execute SonarQube Scanner within Jenkins 2 Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I want to execute a "SonarQube Scanner" Step within my Jenkins 2.x Pipeline.

When I try to create a sample groovy within the pipeline-syntax I only get a groovy script of the following format:

```
step <object of type hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder>
```

Does anyone know what is the correct Step Syntax? E.g. Publish JUnit Report looks like

```
step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: ''])
```

I use the following Versions:

- Jenkins 2.11
- SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1
- SonarQube Plugin 2.4.1

Comment: SonarQube Plugin 2.4.4 also doesn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I got it.
First you have to retrieve your SonarQube Scanner Tool

```
def sonarqubeScannerHome = tool name: 'SonarQubeScanner', type: 'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation'
```

Then you can call sonar-scanner via Shell:

```
sh "${sonarqubeScannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner -e -Dsonar.host.url=..."
```

Answer (score 4):

```
env.sonarHome= tool name: 'scanner-2.4', type: 'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation'

withSonarQubeEnv('sonar.installation') { // from SonarQube servers > name
  sh "${sonarHome}/bin/sonar-runner -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST_URL}  -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN}    -Dsonar.projectName=xxx -Dsonar.projectVersion=xxx -Dsonar.projectKey=xxx -Dsonar.sources=."

}
```

Comment: this will require sonarqube plugin for jenkins >= 2.5 and sonarqube >= 5.2

Answer (score 1):

You can, instead, just provide the full path to ur sonar-runner. As shown in the below snippet.

```
def runSonarScan(sonar_url){
    withEnv(['SONAR_HOST=' + sonar_url]) {
        sh '''
        $/opt/sonarqube/sonar-runner-2.4/bin/sonar-runner -e -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST}
        '''
    }
}
```

If you have specific sonar properties add them as a sonar-project.properties file as shown here [Sonar Project Properties](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)