# SonarQube Scanner fails in a Jenkins pipeline command not found

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarscanner

I'd like to run SonarQube Scanner from a Jenkins pipeline and I followed the documentation.

Regarding the error, it seems that the scanner is present but some commands are not found. My jenkins instance runs in local.

**error message :**

```
 + /usr/local/bin/sonar-scanner
/usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.6.2.2472_1/libexec/bin/sonar-scanner: line 17: dirname: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.6.2.2472_1/libexec/bin/sonar-scanner: line 18: basename: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.6.2.2472_1/libexec/bin/sonar-scanner: line 28: dirname: command not found
File does not exist: //lib/sonar-scanner-cli-4.6.2.2472.jar
'/' does not point to a valid installation directory: /
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

**script pipeline :**

```
    node {
    stage('Preparation') {
        try{
            
        // Clone Project from bitbucket
        git url: 'https://test@bitbucket.org/test/test.git'
        
        }catch(err){
            echo err
        }
    }
    
stage('Sonarqube') {
  
      sh '/usr/local/bin/sonar-scanner'

       
}
    
    stage('end') {  
     echo "Success" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your issue is [`sonar-scanner`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli/blob/fdad4d48ef3d2ef15c48effd841befab5b11f0d3/src/main/assembly/bin/sonar-scanner#L16) rather depends on finding normal unix commands in the environment. `dirname` and `basename` should be in `/usr/bin`. The result is it fails to [build the path](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli/blob/fdad4d48ef3d2ef15c48effd841befab5b11f0d3/src/main/assembly/bin/sonar-scanner#L36) to the binary properly. Check `echo $PATH` &  fix. Easier to fix that than install docker; but not enough info. How did you install cli?

Comment: Also, there's @VonC's [answer to a different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43643924/598141) and older version that would address your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face the same issue in Bitbucket that can be resolved by this.

First, check the path where `sonar-scanner` is installed. You can run the command `which sonar-scanner` to find out its location on the `PATH`, e.g.:

```
/opt/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner
```

Then use the full path to `sonar-scanner` when executing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a docker image in your pipeline to have acces to the sonar-scanner, like this in scripted pipeline :

```
node {
    stage('Preparation') {
        try {
            // Clone Project from bitbucket
            //git url: 'https://test@bitbucket.org/test/test.git'
        } catch(err) {
            echo err
        }
    }
    
    docker.image('sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli').inside {
        stage('Sonarqube') {
            sh 'sonar-scanner'
        }
    }
    
    stage('end') {  
     echo "Success" 
    }
}
```

If you don't have docker installed, you can have a look to the [scanner documentation](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli) to install it during your pipelin or in jenkins itself.

Comment: Not sure how you conclude "Docker" is the solution .. ? OP does not mention using docker.

Comment: Yes, but it is a working solution, and your solution can also work.