# How to use quality gates in Sonarqube to trigger the webhook to jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am reading [this official post](https://blog.sonarsource.com/breaking-the-sonarqube-analysis-with-jenkins-pipelines/) and [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) that explain how should be used the quality gates with jenkins.

My goal is to trigger a build in jenkins if the quality gates is passed.

According to the post, I only have to install a sonarqube and use the snippet of code.

This is the jenkins log after manually triggering the build :

```
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 8cddf9af39adbada9366efd3d707d8056c27cd8d (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 8cddf9af39adbada9366efd3d707d8056c27cd8d
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master 8cddf9af39adbada9366efd3d707d8056c27cd8d
 > git rev-list 8cddf9af39adbada9366efd3d707d8056c27cd8d # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build & SonarQube Scan)
[Pipeline] wrap
[Pipeline] // wrap
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: hudson.AbortException: SonarQube installation defined in this job (My SonarQube Server) does not match any configured installation. Number of installations that can be configured: 1.
If you want to reassign a lot of jobs to a different SonarQube installation see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Reassign+Jobs+to+Another+SonarQube+Instance
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarInstallation.checkValid(SonarInstallation.java:170)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarBuildWrapper.setUp(SonarBuildWrapper.java:81)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreWrapperStep$Execution.start(CoreWrapperStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:184)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: hudson.AbortException: SonarQube installation defined in this job (My SonarQube Server) does not match any configured installation. Number of installations that can be configured: 1.
If you want to reassign a lot of jobs to a different SonarQube installation see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Reassign+Jobs+to+Another+SonarQube+Instance
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.replay(CpsStepContext.java:497)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeDescribable(DSL.java:313)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to prepare withSonarQubeEnv step
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeDescribable(DSL.java:315)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:6)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor499.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:230)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have configured the Sonar jenkins plugins in my jenkins configuration like this:

[image]

I have also installed the **Sonarqube Quality Gates Plugin** in jenkins: *(and not the Quality Gates Plugin which according to the author is deprecated)*

[image]

This is my pipeline groovy script in my job configuration:

```
node {
  stage('SCM') {
    git credentialsId: 'a011099a-e3f6-4d67-9e99-8887b186699d', url: 'ssh://git@module.domain.com/docs/styled.git'
  }
  stage('build & SonarQube Scan') {
    def sonarqubeScannerHome = tool name: 'domain', type: 'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation'
    withSonarQubeEnv('My SonarQube Server') {
        sh "${sonarqubeScannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
    } // SonarQube taskId is automatically attached to the pipeline context
  }
}

// No need to occupy a node
stage("Quality Gate") {
  timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
    def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
    if (qg.status != 'OK') {
      error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
    }
  }
}
```

I am really looking for any way, using gitlab-ci or jenkins to take advantage of the quality gates to decide if an application is deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly says

> SonarQube installation defined in this job (My SonarQube Server) does not match any configured installation.

The [instructions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) say:

> Configure your SonarQube server(s)
>
> - Log into Jenkins as an administrator and go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System:
> - Scroll down to the SonarQube configuration section, click on Add SonarQube, and add the values you're prompted for.

While you've been referring to the docs yourself, it still seems you either haven't done or used a different name for the installation.

In doubt, please edit your post and add a screenshot from the *SonarQube configuration* in *Manage Jenkins*.

Comment: I have added some screenshot of my configuration. I am trying to configure it according to this recommandation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124171/execute-sonarqube-scanner-within-jenkins-2-pipeline with the code snippet generator, would love to see a working example!

Answer (score 1):

you have to install **SonarScanner** and **Quality gate** plugin

And put the configuration as below , the project key you have to generate it from SonarServer Account->Security and put the security key in the Jenkins configuration in Sonarqube section

[image]jpg

Include the quality gate plugin in post build action[image]

In the Sonarserver page you have configure the attribute in Qualitygate section that you are trying the make your build failed for [image]

Comment: What kind of project are you using ? _freestyle_ ? What version of quality gate plugin are you using and what version of sonarqube ? thanks a lot for sharing your configuration. I have added some screenshot of mine

Comment: Its a freestyle project does not use Jenkins file , its a POC  Quality gate version  is latest I guess as I created it yesterday only

Comment: Did you took this plugin (see also the discussion I have with the author: https://github.com/jenkinsci/sonar-quality-gates-plugin/commit/ae995369b3dd94ddc093b1d035928ac707cc7a8d

Comment: There are some issues with latest sonar versions can you please downgrade to a lower version and check

Comment: I solved it with the pipeline by using the NAME of the sonarqube server `withSonarQubeEnv('NAMED_USED_FOR_THE_SONARQUBE_SERVER')`. I am trying to do the same thing with gitlab-ci because jenkins crash when I run jest testing but I don't think this is possible.