# convert SonarQube scanner build step to jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, devops, sonar-runner

I need to convert this build step to Jenkins pipeline,
I tried with the documentation [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/) but no result.
I need to inject it in my jenkinsfile.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R3TP.png)

this is my simple jenkinsfile.

```
timestamps {
node () {
    stage ('MoezProj - Checkout') {
     checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'jenkins', url: 'https://github.com/aditya-sridhar/simple-desktop-app-electronjs.git']]]) 
    }
}
}
```

it works fine when running with Freestyle project but I didn't know how to integrate it in Jenkinsfile as a new stage

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details; your step from jenkinsfile, output msgs, etc.

Comment: I updated the post please check

Comment: It seems to me that your question already has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124171/execute-sonarqube-scanner-within-jenkins-2-pipeline).